# confusion with nested macro expansion

Tags: c, macros

Need explanation on the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x) {
    printf("in foo\n");
    return x;
}

int __foo(int x) {
    printf("in ___foo\n");
    int y = foo(x);
    return y + 1;
}

#define foo(x) __foo(x)
int  main()
{
    printf("=> %d\n", foo(2));
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**
The output I received from above experiment is:

```
in ___foo
in foo
=> 3
```

*Whereas I was expecting that this will result in recursion call ?*

**EDIT:** macro should be defined after definition of `__foo()`

Comment: Is it means that only calls within `main` will be replaced with macro ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbols with two leading underscores are reserved for the "implementation" (compiler and standard library).

Comment: Why did you expect that?

Comment: @AmitSharma No it means all text `foo(something)` where macro `foo` is defined will be replaced with `__foo(something)`.

Comment: @MohitJain, then why I am seeing the shared o/p ?

Comment: Well you've changed it pretty drastically since you originally posted, rendering some of the answers meaningless.

Comment: @TomKarzes, Yes apologies for that. But it  happened due to typo's. :(

Comment: Do not change your question significantly after it had been answered. This might render given answers ununderstandbale. I therefore rolled back your last edit. Add such "changes" as addition to the existing question not as change.

Comment: If you do stupid things in life expect stupid results

Comment: @EdHeal You seem like a super Human, who didn't do stupid things.

Comment: @AmitSharma: He probably did, that's why he knows ... ;-)

Comment: When I do stupid things I tend not to advertise the fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessing using `clang -E`:

```
int foo(int x) {
    printf("in foo\n");
    return x;
}

int __foo(int x) {
    printf("in ___foo\n");
    int y = foo(x);
    return y + 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("=> %d\n", __foo(2));
    return 0;
}
```

This should be clear enough to answer your question.

To get a recursion, try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x) {
    printf("in foo\n");
    return __foo(x);    // <--- Here is the difference
}

int __foo(int x) {
    printf("in ___foo\n");
    int y = foo(x);
    return y + 1;
}

#define foo(x) __foo(x)

int  main()
{
    printf("=> %d\n", foo(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have   updated the code.

Comment: +1 for showing the preprocessor result. You can't understand macro if you don't keep in mind there is a preprocessor generating actual code.

Comment: @AmitSharma Answer updated

Comment: @sunqingyao, So it means it will only replaced the calls done after defining the macro, right ?

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should not link in `C`.

First function `int foo(int x)` would be replaced with

```
int __foo(int x)
```

Because of macro replacement. But later there is another function with the same name which will cause a link time error. This should give a compile time error.

**How to see recursion then**
Move the macro defintion below the first function as:

```
int foo(int x) {
  ...
}

#define foo(x) __foo(x)
int __foo(int x) {
  ...
}
```

---

## After drastic change in post

all text foo(something) where macro foo is defined will be replaced with __foo(something). Until the entry of `main` function, macro `foo` is not defined, so there is no replacement. Inside `main`, macro is defined, and thus all occurrences of `foo(x)` inside `main` are replaced.

## Moral

1. Macros are neither functions nor variables
2. Don't use leading double underscores (from comment)
3. Proofread before asking and don't change your post drastically

Comment: Yes, Already updated the code. Please check. Thanks